# CSS - Hide element if child is empty

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide a parent element, if its child is empty? I know there is the `:empty` selector, but it only works, if the parent doesn't contain anything, including HTML elements.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="center">
        <span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong></strong></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS, which sadly doesn't work this way, but I think you get what I'm trying to do:

```
.label-promotion:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

I want the `<span>` not to appear if  is empty and I'd like to avoid JS for this. Is that possible?

Comment: It isn't empty because there is a `<strong>` in there. Does it have to be there? (edit) Sorry, misread the top of the question. No, you cannot affect the parent based on what the child is doing. That is that **cascading** part of ***C*ascading *S*tyle *S*heet**

Comment: You could remove the strong element and assign a font-weight: bold to the span element. Doing so you could hide the whole span with span:empty { display: none; }

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class:

```css
.label-promotion:has(> strong:empty) {
    display: none;
}
```

---

<strike>If the child of `.label-promotion` will always be a `<strong>`, you can do:</strike>

```
.label-promotion strong:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

to hide the `<strong>`. However, you can not hide the `<span>` itself with CSS.
See this answer to a similar question: [I would like to hide my outer div if inner div is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938365/i-would-like-to-hide-my-outer-div-if-inner-div-is-empty/27938535#27938535)

Comment: It works for me in Chrome, but not in Firefox. It seems empty does not work within has. Could you check it? Thanks!

Comment: @tano unfortunately, the :has selector is not supported in Firefox (yet!)

Comment: The :has selector is now supported in Firefox 121 – [Source](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/121.0/releasenotes/#note-789915).

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to avoid JS for this

Yes, I agree, it's always better to have a pure CSS solution.

But in this instance all you need to do is:

- find all the `.label-promotion` `<spans>`
- loop through them, checking if each has an empty `<strong>`
- if it does, add to the `<span>` the class `.is-empty`

**Working Example:**

```js
// Find all the .label-promotion <spans>
const labelPromotions = document.querySelectorAll('.label-promotion');

// Loop through them... 
for (labelPromotion of labelPromotions) {

  let strong = labelPromotion.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0];
  
  // ... checking if each has an empty <strong> 
  if (strong.textContent === '') {
    
    // If it does, add to to the <span> the class .is-empty
    labelPromotion.classList.add('is-empty');
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.is-empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong>A</strong></span>
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong></strong></span>
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong>C</strong></span>
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong>D</strong></span>
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong></strong></span>
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong></strong></span>
<span class="text-danger label-promotion"><strong>G</strong></span>
```